# Cloned new git repository, have fetch and push urls for old repository

Tags: git

We decided our old remote git repository at dita.git was too cluttered, so we created a new one at dita-new.git. However, when one of my colleagues cloned this repository, her new local got the fetch and push urls to the old remote:

```
$ git remote -v
   origin https://*******/doc/dita.git (fetch)
   origin https://*******/doc/dita.git (push)
   origin https://*******/doc/dita-new.git (push)
```

Her local properties don't contain the old remote, and there is nothing suspicious in her global properties. Her other local repositories, which use the old remote, were cloned using Eclipse, if that matters. She still needs at least one of those local repositories for a branch that wasn't carried over. It does occur to me that the existence of a different origin remote in those repositories might be responsible. However, I cloned the new repository in AFAIK the identical environment and my new local is fine.

Comment: Best to avoid images in questions if at all possible; see [ask]. The `git remote -v` listing output is interesting: it suggests that there are extra `.gitconfig` files involved here, as there are *three* output lines for `origin`, which is downright weird. I suspect some kind of user error, but what, I don't know. Running `git config --list --show-origin` (and pasting all the `remote` lines into the question) might be helpful here.

Comment: Thank you, @torek ! Sorry about the image, was a bit flustered at the time. Fixed it now. We'll try that command Monday.